# Dual monitor display not working with xrandr on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I just finished building my computer and am having trouble getting dual monitors to display properly. Currently, when I run `xrandr` to list the available monitors, I get the following output:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

One of my monitors is 1080p and is being run through HDMI to my computer, the other is 4k being run through DP connection.  If I power on my computer with both displays connected, it will just mirror the display on both screen in 1080p.  This is correct for my 1080p monitor, but obviously not what I want for my 4k monitor.

If I power on the computer with just the 4k monitor or 1080p monitor connected, it displays at the correct resolution, but I still encounter the `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default` error.

I have tried changing out of safe mode in the bios before booting as I saw this could be a potential issue and it didn't help.  I want to be able to change these monitors in my settings and not have the display duplicated but rather extended, but I only have the message `unknown display` within my settings.

I currently am not using a separate graphics card but just the Intel i7-11700K processor. Also, my kernel version is `5.8.0-59-generic`.

Any suggestions on how to get my monitors to properly work?

Answer (score 0):

I apologize in advance if my answer is not appropriate. Have you thought about using the command `cvt X Y Hz`?

Then use `xrandr` to add the new mode and use it.

I put the commands with MY values:

```
$ cvt 1920 1080 60
1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

$ xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1 1920x1080_60.00
```

These are the values of my scripts, the monitor channel name, my resolution. You must adapt them to your needs.

Comment: Yes, have tried this. But the issue is not directly with the modes yet. I am able to adjust the mode for the one monitor I have, but I can't even find/list the second monitor.  Even though I know it is connected through DP, which typically converts to DP-1-1 (on laptop that is what it converts to), my computer doesn't even recognize that connection.

Comment: I think the first thing to detect is whether the second monitor is discoverable. Then, see which device each monitor uses and adapt the mode to each of the monitors

Comment: The second monitor is not discoverable. That is the problem. I know the process of setting the modes per monitor as I have done this previously, but I cannot even discover one of my monitors.